# error message when using process_commands

Tags: discord.py

I get an error message because of the command process_commands and the commands doesn't work, while the evnts do work properly.

```
import discord
from discord import commands
import os

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")
client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Logged in as as {0.user}'.format(client))
 
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == client.user:
    return

  if message.content.startswith('Hello'):
    await message.channel.send('Hello!')

#here comes the error message
  await bot.process_commands(message)

#this command doesn't work
@bot.command()
async def testymesty(ctx):
  await ctx.send('test')

keep_alive()
client.run(os.environ['TOKEN'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple error, you defined client as commands.bot then its going to be :
await client.process_commands(message)
decide between client and bot.

Don't use client and bot at the same time

Comment: You must use client or bot, use bot, remove discord.client defined, and change everything that says client to bot

Comment: Oh, ok thank you, now it worked! But can you explain me what the difference is between commands.Bot and discord.client?

Comment: I believe `commands.Bot` is a slightly extended version of `discord.client`